# How to set the button's style sheet to have several properties?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font: 30pt Comic Sans MS"}
btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
```

I am trying to get my "btn" to be both red and a specific font and size, but can only get one style at a time, in this case; the red command overides the font command.

How can I merge these commands so both are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;"
                        "font: bold 30pt Comic Sans MS")
```

to merge the commands!
Thanks!

Comment: The functions of the form `setSomeProperty()`, replace the previous value, do not add it

Comment: @eyllanesc I will, I have to wait two days before I can choose it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is actually the code you have but you didn't close the brackets for the method nor the double quotes

So this:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font: 30pt Comic Sans MS}
btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
```

Will become this:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {font: 30pt Comic Sans MS}"}
btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
```

Try it, but anyway check this document to reference your code to: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html